# How to select a certain record

Tags: sql, presto

I want to select id from a table like below.
I want to select records which id = '1111' or id = '3333' or id = '5555'.
(I don't like to select records which  A = '0' and B = '0' and C = '0'.)

```
   |id   |A |B |C |
   ---------------
   |1111|0 |1 |1 |
   |2222|0 |0 |0 |
   |3333|1 |1 |1 |
   |4444|0 |0 |0 |
   |5555|0 |0 |1 |
```

I know this sql can realize my request,
but the columns like A or B or C exists more and more(like A,B…X,Y,Z),
so, I don't like to use this query.

```
  select id
  from tbl
  where A = '1' or B = '1' or C = '1'
```

Is there any other way to select the records.

Comment: How big your where cause could be? You can also try out IN clause.

Comment: Can you clarify the **exact** conditions using the **exact** table layout? If you want to select records with the given IDs, why care about whatever the other columns contain?

Answer (score 3):

I think you simply want `IN`:

```
where '1' in (A, B, C, . . . )
```

You still have to list the individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

What about below -

```
select id from tbl
where A + B + C >= 1
```